# Call function if or after an element has been Loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, call

My question is how to trigger or call a function after an element has been loaded or element on the page and don't want to wait for the full page load.

*Example Fiddle:* http://jsfiddle.net/8bJUc/275/ 
*Problem Fiddle:* http://jsfiddle.net/8bJUc/274/

**Call JS:**

```
document.getElementsByClassName("owlCarousel").onLoad = function(){

// do stuff

$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
navigation: true,
pagination: true,
lazyLoad: true
});

};
```

**HTML:**

```
<span class='slide'>
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">  <!-- If .owl-carousel has been loaded -->
  <div>
  <!-- Contents -->
 </div>
</div>
</span>
```

So i mean that if `.slide` has `.owl-carousel` class then call function will be work.
Expecting suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean when the div is loaded or when all the images within the div have been loaded? A div doesn't have an onload event as it's not an external resource and is loaded as part of the body.

Comment: Yes i mean when the div is loaded or when all the images within the div have been loaded, any suggestion?

Comment: Plugin should work when .owl-carousel class on the page.

Answer (score 1):

The div is loaded almost inmediately when the body loads. It has no onload event and the only way to execute a script just after it finished loading is appending the script just after it in the DOM (as some other answers suggested).

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8bJUc/280/) with this option implemented.

**Note** that you need to wrap the script in the header of your page in order to make things work (look at the jsfiddle options I set)

In your HTML it'd look like

```
<head>
    ... rest of your stuff ...
    function launchScript() {
        // do stuff
        $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
            navigation: true,
            pagination: true,
            lazyLoad: true
        });    
    }
</head>
```

And then:

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel"> <!-- If .owl-carousel has loaded-->
...
</div>
<script>
    launchScript();
</script>
```

Comment: It's not working on my Website,I have placed JS as you said, Note: On my site <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel"> is load with some delay, means it's take time to load .owl-carousel , So i thing think we need conditional if statement to make this.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
 $(function(){
     if ($('.slide .owl-carousel').length){ 
         //call function 
     }
 });
```

Comment: Example Fiddle please :)

Answer (score 0):

If it *needs* to be done as soon as possible, you could manually invoke it immediately after the element it relies on is defined.

```js
function asap() {
    // ...
}
```

```html
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
<script>
asap();
</script>
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r3roL44z/) (open your console)

Comment: Example Fiddle please :)

Comment: my question was for CLASS not for ID, for some reason i need Class, so any suggestions for class?

Comment: @Aabira it makes no difference, just access by class instead. The point is that the node exists

Comment: Hi dear it's not working, Plugin should work when .owl-carousel class on the page, but it run without .owl-carousel class, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/8bJUc/276/

Comment: i means, i have removed `.owl-carousel` class from here `<div id="owl-demo" class="none">` my question is call only when `.owl-carousel` class on the page.